# Dynamic Menu filled with input form

Tags: html, dom, menu

I'm trying to figure out how to make this:

I got 3 inputs, one menu and something to show the selected option(after fill the input form, while it's filled it might show any text).

So let's begin:

what I want to do is: fill the 3 inputs forms, and when I click on Submit button, it will fill the menu with what I wrote on the inputs forms and when I choose something on this menu, it will be shown in a input form as well

thanks in advance !

I tried this:

[My test](http://pastebin.com/LbXJQQNg)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or were you just looking for someone to do this for you?

Comment: I tried something, please see on my post. thanks !!